# Expandable string substitution

Tags: macros, expansion

I am trying to define a macro

```
\formatstr{\mystring}{(string empty)}{the string is: #1}
```

which expands to `(string empty)` when `\mystring` is empty (as judged, e.g. by etoolbox's `\csdefempty`) and expands to `the string is: \mystring` otherwise.

I could write, for example,

```
\newcommand*\formatstr[3]{%
  \def\fmt##1{#3}%
  \ifdefempty#1{#2}{\fmt{#1}}%
}
```

which works as I want, except for the fact that `\formatstr` itself is not expandable because of the `\def` assignment.

Is there any other way in which I could substitute the `#1` in the third argument of `\formatstr` with `\mystring` in an expandable way?

**Edit: Let me try to more clearly explain what I'm trying to do**

Using `etoolbox` I can type things such as

```
\ifdefempty{\mystring}{(empty string)}{the string \mystring\ is funny}
```

But this gets tedious if I have to write

```
\ifdefempty{\mystringwithaverylongname}{(empty string)}{the string \mystringwithaverylongname\ is long}
```

So what I would like to be able to write is

```
\formatstr{\mystringwithaverylongname}{(empty string)}{some string #1 is nice}
```

Or perhaps

```
\formatstr{\mystringwithaverylongname}{(empty string)}{i've heard that :str is interesting}
```

What I want to know if is it possible to substitute the `#1` (or `:str`) in the third argument with the contents coming from the first?

Comment: I have a feeling this has come up before probably with an egreg answer.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you just after `\ifx#1\@empty`?

Comment: No, the emptiness check is fine, the problem is the `\def`!

Comment: I don't see why you need the `\def` at all. If you want to use `\ifdefempty`, why not just `\ifdefempty{#1}...`?

Comment: Because I want to replace `the string is: #1` with `the string is: \mystring`.

Comment: Basically, I'm lazy and I don't want to type `\mystring` twice when using `\formatstr`.

Comment: @JuanA.Navarro I believe that you need an assignment somewhere, in order to use `#1` or any other fixed marker. The "four arguments" approach seems the best you can get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a wrapper around `\ifdefempty` functioning as an argument processor. For instance:

```
\def\myifdefempty#1#2#3:str#4|{%
  \ifdefempty{#1}{#2}{#3#1#4}%
}
```

Full minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\formatstr}[3]{%
  \myifdefempty{#1}{#2}#3|%
}

\def\myifdefempty#1#2#3:str#4|{%
  \ifdefempty{#1}{#2}{#3#1#4}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\def\mystring{}

\section{\formatstr{\mystring}{an empty string}{the string :str is funny}}

\def\mystring{`a'}

\section{\formatstr{\mystring}{an empty string}{the string :str is funny}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this is perhaps closer to what was asked for but probably worth noting that :str needs to be at the top level not in `{}` groups. (Of course a similar restriction is enforced in my version by splitting the argument:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Some day, I’ll understand TeX a bit :-)

Comment: Very nice and very creative! I was trying to fish for something more general, but I'm quite happy with this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The usual idiom is something like

```
\makeatletter

\begingroup
\lccode`\!=0
\lowercase{\endgroup
\newcommand*\formatstr[3]{%
  \if!#1!%
   \expandafter\@firstofthree
   \else
   \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi{#2}{#3}{#1}}}

\long\def\@firstofthree#1#2#3{#1}


\makeatother

\def\foo{}


\typeout{A: \formatstr\foo{string is emty}{the string is: \fmt}}


\def\fmt#1{[[#1]]}
\def\foo{hello}


\typeout{B: \formatstr\foo{string is emty}{the string is: \fmt}}

\stop
```

which produces the output (in `\typeout` to show it is expandable

```
A: string is emty
B: the string is: [[hello]]
```

---

Or this version which does not require a `\fmt` helper macro.

Here, as noted in comments, the syntax is

```
  \fmtstring\token{empty}{non-empth-pre}{non-empty-post}
```

with `empty` being used in the empty case and the expansion of

```
non-empth-pre\token non-empty-post
```

being used in the non-empty case.

```
A: string is empty
B: the string is: [hello]
```

from the slightly simpler code:

```
\makeatletter

\begingroup
\lccode`\!=0
\lowercase{\endgroup
\newcommand*\formatstr[4]{%
  \if!#1!%
   \expandafter\@firstoftwo
   \else
   \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi{#2}{#3#1#4}}}



\makeatother

\def\foo{}
\typeout{A: \formatstr\foo{string is empty}{the string is: [}{]}}



\def\foo{hello}
\typeout{B: \formatstr\foo{string is empty}{the string is: [}{]}}

\stop
```

Comment: But if I want to change the output of the non-empty case, then I have to redefine `\fmt` before using `\formatstr`. But that's the information that I wanted to pass as the third argument of `\formatstr`!

Comment: well... if you just want it to come at the end the you don't need fmt at all. If you want to be able to make it appear in the middle of some arbitrary string then you need to make a non-expandable definition somewhere. Would it be ok to have tree arguments  `\formatstr\token{empty}{not-empty-pre}{not-empty-post}` so you could go `\formatstr\foo{string is emty}{the string is:[[}{]]}`  That wouldn't require `\fmt`

Comment: Yes, I want it to show possibly in the middle of somethings. I've considered, as you mention, passing four arguments rather than three, but I thought the other syntax is nicer/more concise. My question was whether that was possible at all. In fact, I don't really care if I have to use `#1` or `:str` on the non-empty case; what I would like is to be able to substitute such marker with the `\mystring` coming as the first argument, so that I don't have to type the contents of the first argument twice.

Comment: since the first argument os always a single token, it would be a lot easier with a lot less restrictions just to use it in the third argument `\formatstr{\mystring}{(string empty)}{the string is: \mystring}` seems as easy to enter as the version in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what Joseph Wright is saying, which sounds logical to me, but I don't think I understand the OP well. `\ifdefempty` is expandable in a rather expensive way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*\formatstr[3]{\ifdefempty{#1}{#2}{#3#1}}
\newcommand*\bformatstr[3]{\ifblank{#1}{#2}{#3{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\def\fmt#1{[[#1]]}
\def\foo{}
\def\vgap{\par\bigskip}

\textbf{Case A1}: \formatstr\foo{string is empty}{the string is: \fmt}
\vgap
\textbf{Case A2}: \bformatstr{}{string is empty}{the string is: \fmt}
\vgap
\def\foo{hello}
\textbf{Case B1}: \formatstr\foo{string is empty}{the string is: \fmt}
\vgap
\textbf{Case B2}: \bformatstr{hello}{string is empty}{the string is: \fmt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\ifdefempty` ignores prefixes. Moreover, control sequences whose replacement text is blank space are considered empty, too. The former is a documented feature, the latter is undocumented.